# error: Comparator is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, comparator

I am trying to compile ths below code in my windows system.

```
 import java.util.*;
 class Mycomparator1 implements Comparator
 {
  public int compare(Object obj1,Object obj2)
  {
    Integer I1=(Integer)obj1;
    Integer I2=(Integer)obj2;
    return I1.compareTo(I2);
    return I2.compareTo(I1);
    return -I1.compareTo(I2);
    return -I2.compareTo(I1);
    return -1;
    return 0;
  }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        TreeSet t=new TreeSet(new Comparator());
    t.add(20);
    t.add(0);
    t.add(15);
    t.add(5);
    t.add(10);
    System.out.println(t);
   }
  }
```

when i compiling the code, i am getting the below error

```
 MyComparator1.java:18: error: Comparator is abstract; cannot be instantiated
             TreeSet t=new TreeSet(new Comparator());
                                  ^
 Note: MyComparator1.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
 1 error
```

how can i solve this type of error?

Comment: Note: you probably want `class Mycomparator1 implements Comparator<Integer>` or at least `class Mycomparator1 implements Comparator<Object>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
TreeSet t=new TreeSet(new MyComparator1());
```

as you want to use your comparator.

BTW, you should rethink your `compare` function, as you have compilation error there - the function will always return the first `return` statement, generating `unreachable code` error.

Answer (score 2):

A `Comparator` is an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html), interfaces cannot be instantiated, therefore you must create an instance of `MyComparator1`.

```
TreeSet t=new TreeSet(new MyComparator1());
```

For this code to compile you must also modify the `compare` method to remove the unreachable return statements.  Anything after the first `return` statement will never be executed.

```
  public int compare(Object obj1,Object obj2)
  {
    Integer I1=(Integer)obj1;
    Integer I2=(Integer)obj2;
    return I1.compareTo(I2);
    //removed 4 other return statements
  }
```

Comment: getting error,   MyComparator1.java:9: error: unreachable statement
                return I2.compareTo(I1);
                ^

Comment: That cannot even compile. The method compare() has several return statements. You can only have one return for each case

Comment: That is because 5 of the 6 return statements will never be executed in the `compare` method.